# Encountering a non-numerical value for a derivative when evaluating NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve an ODE. I am trying to get a numerical solution. My code is:

```
T[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}

BB[xx_, yy_, zz_] := 
  (μ NN II)/(2 π Sqrt[xx^2 + yy^2 + zz^2]) * 
     Derivative[1, 0][r][ArcTan[yy/xx], ArcSin[zz/R]]

ecsdiff = 
  {m*D[D[x1[t], t], t] == q*((Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 3]*D[x2[t], t]) - (D[x3[t], t]* Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 2])), 
   m*D[D[x2[t], t], t] == q*((D[x3[t], t]*Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 1]) - (D[x1[t], t]*Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 3])),
   m*D[D[x3[t], t], t] == q*((Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 2]*D[x1[t], t]) - (D[x2[t], t]*Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 1])),
   x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1, x3[0] == 0, 
   x1'[0] == 1, x2'[0] == -1, x3'[0] == 0.5};

sols = 
  Chop[
  Flatten[
    Quiet @ 
      NDSolve[ecsdiff, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, Infinity},
        Method -> 
          {"EventLocator",
           "Event" -> {x1[t] + 50, x2[t] + 50, x3[t] + 50},
           "EventAction" :> Throw[tf = t, "StopIntegration"], 
           "Direction" -> -1}, 
        MaxSteps -> Infinity]]]
```

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

I cannot seem to get rid of the error shown above, any help is appreciated

Comment: Your DE must be numerical: Several parameters `m, NN,II,...` are undefined!

Comment: You are right , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. It is a comment, but it is too long and complicated to be written as normal comment.

Your definition of `BB` is  incomprehensible to me. You are taking the derivative w.r.t. `r`, but the variable `r` does not appear anywhere in the expression. Further, since `BB` is a function of three variables, you need to use the three-variable form of `Derivative`. Ignoring the undefined constants, `BB` would be valid if defined like this or something similar:

```
BB[xx_, yy_, zz_] :=
  Block[{r},
    r[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][r][ArcTan[yy/xx], ArcSin[zz/r[xx, yy, zz], zz]/r[xx, yy, zz]]
```

This version of `BB` will evaluate

```
Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 1]
Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 2]
Part[BB[x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]], 3]
```

[image: result]